# GWT charts in vaadin with html included (in org chart)

Tags: gwt, google-visualization, vaadin

I'm using the [Visualizations Addon for Vaadin](http://phil.virtuallypreinstalled.com/VisDemo) and I want to implement the org chart and it works perfect.

What I want to do is add html labels to it, as the [original gwt chart demo](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart) shows.

How can I do it?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the HTML labels, you need to add HTML to the labels and set the `allowHtml` option to `true`.  I'm not familiar with the Vaadin implementation, but based on the demos, you probably want something like this:

```
OrganizationalChart oc = new OrganizationalChart();
oc.setSizeFull();
oc.setOption("size", "medium");
oc.setOption("allowCollapse", false);
oc.setOption("allowHtml", true);
oc.add("CEO", "", "<b>CEO</b> Bert Big");
oc.add("CIO", "CEO", "<b>CIO</b> Charly IT");
oc.add("CFO", "CEO", "<b>CFO</b> Funny Muny");
oc.add("Strategy", "CIO", "<b>Strategy</b> Willy Wonder");
```